# Explanation of Raphael js drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, raphael

view-source:http://raphaeljs.com/touches.html

http://raphaeljs.com/touches.html

I'd love it if somebody explained why this drag 'n' drop example works. I can gather roughly what each function is doing but I can't piece together why this moves when there's nothing telling it to move.

Comment: "there's nothing telling it to move" - what makes you think that? There are multiple calls to an `.animate()` method, as well as Raphael's [`.drag()`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.drag) method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `move` function behaves as a callback, and it takes 2 arguments, `dx, dy`. They stand for delta-X and delta-Y respectively.

If you see this line:

```
this.attr({cx: this.ox + dx, cy: this.oy + dy});
```

Then you will notice that ox and oy stand for original-X and original-Y respectively.

Thus you can deduct that the attr function is being called with arguments that specify original X + delta X and original Y + delta Y.

Make sense?

Do not get confused with the animate calls - they are for expanding/contracting the shape on start/stop. Every time you move the mouse, the `move` function is called, and the `attr` is updated.

Comment: Thankyou there! Really helpful and well explained. I couldn't understand what the stuff you mentioned was doing.